# I am one of many! Who am I?

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme, poetry

```
I am one of many brothers & sisters,
Maybe the most important of all.

I am made fun of because I'm different
I do not deny I am the fattest of them all!

Indeed I bring order to our master,
without me their words would be in duress.

You can see a part of me everywhere
Near you or above, in the vast expanses.

The other part is where many 
like to drown their sorrows & some de-stress

My methods are unconventional though,
through divide I bring peace!

The world would be chaotic,
If my existence you cease!
```

**Who am I?**

This is my first puzzle ever, so please excuse noviceness. Hence, there may be multiple right answers and hence try to explain your answer in the context of the riddle!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are

> The Space Bar

I am one of many brothers & sisters,
Maybe the most important of all.

I am made fun of because I'm different
I do not deny I am the fattest of them all!

> The space bar is the largest key on a keyboard

Indeed I bring order to our master,
without me their words would be in duress.

> Without the space bar, all of the words you type would be connected.

You can see a part of me everywhere
Near you or above, in the vast expanses.

> This describes the word "space."

The other part is where many
like to drown their sorrows & some de-stress

> This describes the word "bar."

My methods are unconventional though,
through divide I bring peace!

The world would be chaotic,
If my existence you cease!

> A space bar divides characters, andthisclauseisprettychaotic!

Comment: Well done @Rob F.! I was sure though there were going to be more answers :(!